# My Site Crashes

Tags: javascript

My Site Crashes whenever I press The Play Button, And I Don't Know Why. I Can Guess Its Something To Do With The While Loop Repeating Forever, But I Don't Know Any Ways To Make My Code Not Crash. Here Is The While Loop:
(by the way its supposed to be a repeat forever loop)

```
document.onkeydown=function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 65) {
        x = x + 1;
    }
var display = "";
for (i = 0; i < x; i++){
     var fruit = Math.ceiling((Math.random() * 20) + 1);  
     if (fruit < 5) {
         fruit = fruit + 5;
     }

}
display = display + "<==>";
document.getElementById("game").innerHTML=display;
};
```

Comment: You Should Format Your Code And Also Why Are You Capitalizing Everything Like This? That Looks Really Unusual.

Comment: Of course that's going to give you an infinite loop, `10` will always `=== 10`.

Comment: hmm I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. It doesn't seem like you are doing anything with `fruit`, and you are putting the string `"<==>"` in your `game` element any time a key is pressed. What is your intention?

Answer (score 0):

You should listen for the keydown event on the document instead of using an infinite loop.

```
document.onkeydown=function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 65) {
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: That code does help, but it only works the first time I press a. I need the function to be called anytime I press a.

Comment: It should be triggering every time you press a. Can you update your question with your updated code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is checking to make sure 10 is still equal to 10.  Last I checked, it still was, but you never know - if that ever changes, you want to be the first to know!

---

Seriously, though.  I'm not sure what you're trying to check, but 10 is one number that won't be changing for a while...